# Can't login into my Ubuntu PC

Tags: login, 19.10

I am not able to login into my Ubuntu PC. It simply rejects the password.
Error message comes:

*Sorry, that didn't work. Please try again.*

I did **not** change the password. I had used it last night only, but now I am not even able to login.

My OS is Ubuntu 19.10

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Please note caps lock is on.

Comment: Yeah...I know. My password contains it

Comment: Take a deep breath. Go get a sandwich. Then try again. On one historic occasion, I entered my password wrong five times in a row...each time absolutely certain I had entered it correctly. But I had not. My password had not been magically changed.

Comment: Did you tried in console mode?

Comment: I am a new user to Linux. Dont know much about all that.

Comment: As @user535733 says, do try again. Check if every keypress shows a new circle. A faulty keyboard, or forgetting to set NumLock could be the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that my PC was hacked, and its password remotely changed? I tried ctrl+alt+F4 and switched to terminal. But it still shows incorrect login. Although, there is some wierd activity. The terminal screen abruptly keeps clearing up to ask for the login details again and again.

Comment: Apparently, if I type the capitals using Shift button, then the password is accepted, but not using the CAPS LOCK. I dont know what the reason is, but it worked. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if I type the capitals using Shift button, then the password is accepted, but **not** using the CAPS LOCK. I dont know what the reason is, but it worked.

I searched a bit. It looks like in my recent updates, this new setting was added. So it is that. Use shift instead of Caps Lock.